# input select box don't use a padding in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, padding

I have a input select box and I have to align the text in this box.
In Google Chrome, Firefox and IE <= 9 it works fine.
But the Safari don't use the padding..

Here my code:

```
<select class="anrede1">
    <option>Frau</option>
    <option>Herr</option>
</select>

.anrede1, .land {
    font-family:'Roboto Condensed';
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #575656;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 42px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 17px;
    border: 2px solid #e1eef9;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jhne7pfe/

Some ideas to fix that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Its a late answer but I was searching for a solution to the same problem for a while.  Using text-indent shifted the elements around the input element and the padding was still ignored.

```
-webkit-appearance: textfield;
```

Using that solved my problem, hope this saves someone else time.

Answer (score 1):

It's not work anymore. 
<s>`-webkit-appearance: textfield;`</s> ❌


If you want padding in Safari device. You have to use: 
`select{-webkit-appearance: initial;-moz-appearance: initial;appearance: initial;}` ✅

```css
select{
    -webkit-appearance: initial;
    -moz-appearance: initial;
    appearance: initial;
    
    padding: 15px 40px;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Select A</option>
  <option>Select B</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know W3 specs don't allow to use padding in select fields. So Safari doesn't support it.

But you can use the following instead of `padding-left`:

```
text-indent:17px;
```

This should work fine.

Comment: I'm using firefox. Editing your fiddle and updating it with 'text-indent' works fine for me.

Comment: OK, I see... Thats awesome. I didn't notice before this phenomenom... Let me see, if I find another solution

Comment: OK, as I don't have a safari installed here, I hope this helps: 
'padding-left:17px;
-webkit-padding-start:17px;'
and forget about 'text-indent' - unfortunately I also have no jsfiddle account yet. Will be done as soon as possible ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if my last comment reply came through:

As I don't have a Safari installed here, I hope this helps. Try to use:

```
padding-left:17px; 
-webkit-padding-start:17px;
```

instead of

```
text-indent: 17px;
```

The `-webkit-padding-start` is for chrome and safari browsers only and should be ignored automatically, if `padding-left` works.

Unfortunately I also have no jsfiddle account yet.

Will be done as soon as possible ;-)

Comment: Hi :)
same problem here.
It's works fine but not in the safari..
http://jsfiddle.net/jhne7pfe/7/

I think I have to check if somebody comes with the safari on my page and include the text-indent.. or have you another idea?

Comment: no sorry, seems to be the best way to check users browser and take action on it. Just for interest: Are you trying safari for Windows or on Mac?

Comment: Ehm.. Mac and Windows. Both have problem with the padding. BUT the iPad works fine :D

Comment: Hey @cypher75 maybe it doesn't work because I have an old safari installed :p Version 5 .. I can't test it with a newer Version. Maybe that is the problem.